# How Do I Associate Two Arrays (One with "Time Clock Punch Dates", One with "Time Worked")?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have two arrays:

1) Scheduled Date of Work Shift Schedule (can be multiple entries for each Scheduled Date, as some people have multiple shifts in one day)

2) Hours Worked for Each Shift

For example,

1) ['07/19/2019', '07/19/2019', '07/20/2019', '07/21/2019']

2) ['6', '2', '8', '8']

The goal is to loop through each date, and display the Hours Worked for each date in total, as well as the individual "shift hours".

For example, the end result should show:

07/19/2019: 8

6, 2

07/20/2019: 8

8

07/21/2019: 8

8

Right now, my code simply loops through both arrays using a number to associate each Date, so I get the following output:

07/19/2019: 6

07/19/2019: 2

07/20/2019: 8

07/20/2019: 8

I am new to JavaScript. Perhaps I need to create some sort of association using 'map', 'reduce', or 'filter'?

I am not quite sure where to start.

```
for (let x = 0; x < shifts.length; x++) { 
    shift_date.push(shifts.date);
    shift_hours.push(shifts.hour);
}

for (let y = 0; x < shifts_date.length) {
    htmlOutput += "Date: " + shift_date[y];
    htmlOutput += "Hours Worked: " + shift_hours[y];
}
```

Comment: IF one of these answers answers your question, please accept that answer by clicking the the check next to it.  If not, can you please provide feedback why none of these answers have resolved your issue?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thank you for the excellent answer!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comments you want to create a slightly more complex object of the arrays.

Here, I create an object to namespace things and then fill it out with the values.

In the end, you can simply  use the `mywork` object to get any of the information you need.

For example `console.log(mywork.workgroups[0].date,mywork.workgroups[0].totalhours);` outputs:

> 07/19/2019 8

Or you you loop through them as I show here.

At the end, I added a bit of jQuery code to display this in a page, ignore that part if you want, it is only to show how to use the objects.

```js
var mywork = mywork || {
  workdates: ['07/19/2019', '07/19/2019', '07/20/2019', '07/21/2019', '07/22/2019','07/22/2019'],
  workduration: ['6', '2', '8', '8','7','6'],
  workgroups: [],
  uniquedates: [],
  showWork: function() {
    $.each(this.workgroups, function(index, value) {
      //console.log("dates:", this.workdates);
      let item = $('.item').first().hide().clone();
      item.find('.item-date').html(value.date);
      item.find('.item-total').html(value.totalhours);
      item.find('.item-hours').html("("+value.hours.join(',')+")");
      $('.container').append(item.show());
    })
  }
};

function setThingsUp(w) {
  w.uniquedates = w.workdates
    .filter(function(element, index, thisarray) {
      return thisarray.indexOf(element) === index;
    }, w);

  w.uniquedates.forEach(function(udate, uindex, ar) {
    // console.log("ud:", udate);
    let wg = {
      "date": udate,
      "totalhours": 0,
      "hours": []
    };
    w.workdates
      .forEach(function(element, index, thisarray) {
        if (udate === element) {
          let h = w.workduration[index] * 1;
          wg.hours.push(h);
          wg.totalhours = wg.totalhours + h;
        }
      }, w);
    w.workgroups.push(wg)
  }, w);

 // console.log("u:", w.uniquedates);
 // console.log("wg:", w.workgroups);
}

setThingsUp(mywork);
//console.log("work:", mywork.workdates);
// console.log(mywork.workgroups[0].date, mywork.workgroups[0].totalhours);
// show the data for each date
mywork.workgroups.forEach(function(wg, index, thisarray) {
 // console.log(wg.date, wg.totalhours, wg.hours);
});
$(function() {
  mywork.showWork();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Date:<span class="item-date"></span> Total Hours:<span class="item-total"></span> Hours:<span class="item-hours"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce()` for this :

```js
const dates = ["07/19/2019", "07/19/2019", "07/20/2019", "07/21/2019"];

const hours = ["6", "2", "8", "8"];

const result = dates.reduce((all, curr, ndx) => {
  all[curr] = (all[curr] | 0) + +hours[ndx];
  return all;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfect for giving me the total hours for each day, but I actually had to edit my question because I forgot one requirement - I need to be able to display the individual hours for each date. For example: 

`07/19/2019: 8 - 

(6, 2)

07/20/2019: 8 -

(8)

07/21/2019: 8 -

(8)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is store the arrays as pairs, and put that into a loop. What I mean:
Right now you have this set up:

```
let shift_dates = ['07/19/2019', '07/19/2019', '07/20/2019', '07/21/2019']
let shift_hours = ['6',          '2',          '8',          '8']
```

We could set it up like this:

```
let shifts = [{'date':'07/19/2019', 'hours':'6'},
             {'date':'07/19/2019', 'hours':'2'},
             {'date':'07/20/2019', 'hours':'8'},
             {'date':'07/21/2019', 'hours':'8'}]
```

Note that the first implementation is two separate indexed arrays, while the second implementation is an **array of objects** containing info about the shift. As a handy side effect, this array structure mimics how a database would return spreadsheet rows.

After that, you can simply iterate through your data as before:

```
for(var i = 0; i < shifts.length; i++) {

   let shift = shifts[i]; //This object contains your info
   htmlOutput += "Date: " + shift.date;
   htmlOutput += "Hours Worked:" + shift.hours;
}
```

Note that using this implementation, you could add more fields, such as the employee's name or the shift leader.

```
    let shifts = [{'date':'07/19/2019', 'hours':'6', 'supervisor':'tommy'},
                  {'date':'07/21/2019', 'hours':'8', 'supervisor':'fred'}]; //Row 1
    let x = shifts[1].supervisor; //'fred'
```

In the end, how you loop through this data really depends on how you're getting it.

**TLDR**
Use an array of objects to group data together, like in the rows of a spreadsheet.

Comment: How can I "push" my objects into the array? Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm brand new to JS and I've been racking my brain for 3 weeks on this current project. I *really* appreciate your help, Andy!

Comment: @JohnMartinelli How are you getting input in? From your question it seems like an object, but it's not possible to iterate through is like that. Do you plan to get data from a spreadsheet/ database, where data comes in rows?

Comment: I am getting input from an API call that returns this data into a multi-dimensional array.